# Combining Uneven Variables in to One Variable - R

Tags: r

I wondered if anyone could help with the following, please?

I'd like to transform the 3 uneven length wide form variables (X1-X3) into one long-form variable.

The long-form variable will then form the input into a multi-density GGPlot.

Beforehand, when I used melt, the density plot was characterised by reports of missing values. So i'd like to try a different approach to test whether the original approach was at fault.

All help would be appreciated.

Previous (partially successful attempt):

```
X1 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
X2 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 150, replace = TRUE)
X3 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 250, replace = TRUE)


maxlength = max(length(X1), length(X2), length(X3))
XX1 = c(X1, rep(NA, maxlength - length(X1)))
XX2 = c(X2, rep(NA, maxlength - length(X2)))
XX3 = c(X3, rep(NA, maxlength - length(X3)))

Y <- data.frame(XX1, XX2,XX3)
YY <- melt(Y)
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output here? If you are creating a density plot, it's not clear why all groups should have the same number of observations. It should be fine if they don't. What plotting code are you trying exactly?

Comment: Hi @MrFlick. I'd like to essentially convert the data from wide to long format. After getting it in long format, I'd like to create an overlapping density plot. However, as it stands my wide-format data is of uneven column length. Therefore, I've had issues combining the data into a single long-form format

Comment: So what exactly is your input? X1,X2,X3? Or Y? or YY?

Comment: The input into the ggplot would be YY in the mock example above. The wide form data of different lengths is X1-X3. When I use the above method to get YY as an input for the overlapping density plot, I get an error of Warning message:
Removed 2126 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_density()`)" - Which speaks to me as if I am doing something wrong in the wide-long transorfmation.

Comment: Try something like `stack(mget(paste0("X", 1:3))) |> ggplot(aes(values, fill=ind)) + geom_density(alpha=.4)` instead. You don't need to create the data in the `Y` shape.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have N datasets defined as vectors and you want to create one probability density plot to compare the different distributions.

You are right that the best way to do this is to first get your vectors into one dataframe, and then use [ggplot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/). You can have a datarame of two columns: values and vector name. Then you can use the vector name as the grouping condition in ggplot. Here's what the dataframe would look like:

[image]

If you are using ggplot, then perhaps you can just use a full [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) approach. Below is code for two ways to get the vectors into one dataframe. The first way just hard codes your 3 vectors and is closer to what you were trying to do. The second way is more extensible; define your list of vectors once and then use map create the columns.

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Data
X1 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
X2 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 150, replace = TRUE)
X3 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 250, replace = TRUE)

# Create dataframe Option 1
# df <- tibble(value = c(X1, X2, X3),
#              group = factor(rep(c("X1", "X2", "X3"), 
#                                 times = c(length(X1), length(X2), length(X3)))))

# Create dataframe Option 2
data_list <- list(Data1 = X1, Data2 = X2, Data3 = X3)

df <- data_list %>% 
  imap(~data.frame(value = .x, group = .y)) %>%
  bind_rows()

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x = value, fill = group)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + 
  labs(title = "Title",
       x = "Value",
       y = "Probability Density")
```

Which produces this plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a repex followed by a description of the behaviours you observed.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1) # To ensure sample() results are reproducible

X1 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 100, replace = TRUE)
X2 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 150, replace = TRUE)
X3 <- sample(seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = 0.005), size = 250, replace = TRUE)

# Stack data into a single dataframe using base R
df <- stack(mget(paste0("X", 1:3)))

# Plot data
ggplot(df, aes(x = values, fill = ind)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.33,
               linewidth = .25) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend Title",
                    values = c("#ff6db6", "#b66dff", "#db6d00"),
                    labels = c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3")) +
  labs(title = "Probability Density for Variables 1, 2, and 3",
       x = "Variable Value",
       y = "Density") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1), ylim = c(0, 1.4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(seq(0, 1.4, by = 0.35))) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = rel(0.75)))
```

[image: result]

As you noted regarding your approach, the shorter vectors get padded with NA values so that each vector has the same length. For example:

```
tail(Y)
    XX1 XX2   XX3
245  NA  NA 0.465
246  NA  NA 0.750
247  NA  NA 0.910
248  NA  NA 0.320
249  NA  NA 0.705
250  NA  NA 0.960
```

When you pivoted Y to long format, the NA values get included. So when you plot YY using `ggplot()`, it lets you know some data are missing e.g.:

> Warning message: Removed 250 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density())"

In some cases it is [desirable to include NA values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77979559/2530121), but it is not necessary in your case. Either way, your data **will still plot correctly** even with the NA values. By example, the example plot image above was made from a dataset using the following method. Note that `reshape2::melt()` was deprecated some time ago, so if you do need to pivot data with the same structure as Y, do this:

```
library(tidyr)

YY <- pivot_longer(Y, cols = everything())

YY
# A tibble: 750 × 2
   name  value
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 XX1   0.975
 2 XX2   0.55 
 3 XX3   0.45 
 4 XX1   0.83 
 5 XX2   0.375
 6 XX3   0.52 
 7 XX1   0.82 
 8 XX2   0.6  
 9 XX3   0.755
10 XX1   0.38 
# ℹ 740 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```